# HttpErrorResponse & Spring Bad Request: Required request body is missing

Tags: javascript, java, angular, http, spring-mvc

I've been running into a Bad Request.

Server side error:

```
Required request body is missing error
```

Client side error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request",
                   url: "http://localhost:9000/api/create-risk", ok: false, …}
```

I've tested the API with my built in swagger component and I get a 201 response with the proper object being created & the expected response.  I have a feeling this is an oversight somewhere on my part but Ive been looking at this code for hours now and cant seem to find the disconnect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

API:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/create-risk", produces = 
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Risk createRisk(
    @RequestBody Risk risk
) {
    log.debug("REST request to save Risk : {}", risk);
    Risk createdRisk = new Risk();
    createdRisk.setPocFirstName(risk.getPocFirstName());
    riskManagementRepository.save(createdRisk);
    return createdRisk;
}
```

Angular RiskModel

```
export interface IRiskModel {
id?: any;
login?: string;
firstName?: string;
lastName?: string;
email?: string;
activated?: boolean;
langKey?: string;
authorities?: any[];
createdBy?: string;
createdDate?: Date;
lastModifiedBy?: string;
lastModifiedDate?: Date;
password?: string;
```

}

```
export class RiskModel implements IRiskModel {
constructor(
    public id?: any,
    public firstName?: string,
) {
    this.id = id ? id : null;
    this.firstName = firstName ? firstName : null;
}
```

}

Risk Component HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <form name="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="risk.firstName" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button (click)="saveRisk()" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Create-Risk TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {RiskModel,RiskManagementService} from 'app/core';


@Component({
selector: 'jhi-create-risk',
templateUrl: './create_risk.component.html',
styleUrls: ['create_risk.scss']
})
export class CreateRiskComponent implements OnInit {
risk: RiskModel;
inProduction: boolean;
swaggerEnabled: boolean;

constructor(
    private riskManagementService: RiskManagementService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(({ risk }) => {
        this.risk = risk.body ? risk.body : risk});
};

saveRisk() {
    this.riskManagementService.createRisk(this.risk).subscribe(response 
=> response);
}
```

}

Risk Service TS

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SERVER_API_URL } from 'app/app.constants';
import {IRiskModel} from 'src/main/webapp/app/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class RiskManagementService {
public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/create-risk';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

createRisk(risk: IRiskModel): Observable<HttpResponse<IRiskModel>> {
    return this.http.post<IRiskModel>(this.resourceUrl, risk, {observe: 
    'response'});
}
```

}

Comment: in the java controller, you create a new risk, set an attribute and then you persist it. Why don't you save the one you receive from the rest call?

Comment: I removed the instantiation of the newRisk & instead called a get/set on the Risk @ResponseBody object and returned it...still the same Bad Request & 400 error on Server/Client side.

Comment: bad request means that the ui model is not one to one with the backend, the fields do not properly map, or the validations on the backend are not met